# Examples of disc brakes causing injury in pro races

Tags: disc-brake, crash, uci

Before disc brakes became UCI legal there was a lot of people arguing that they were more dangerous than standard v brakes in bunch races. Often it was highlighted that a very hot spinning metal disc could slice through skin or tissue very easily.

Discs have now been in pro and local races for quite a while - I was wondering if there were any examples of this actually happening?

Cheers

Comment: Here's an account, but there is no actual proof: 
 https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/racing/paris-roubaix-23-rider-suffers-gruesome-wound-leg-says-caused-disc-brake-425947

Comment: The proper question would probably be "Are disk brakes considerably less safe than rim brakes". Or what is the goal of the question, actually?

Comment: How often have handle bar ends, or rim brakes, or shift levers or derailleurs or ... caused injuries in a bike race? Are the number of disk brake related injuries in line with other types of injuries or are they significantly higher or lower? Otherwise, just asking about a single data point isn't very instructive.

Answer (score 2):

Reports are becoming more common:
https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/cyclocross-rider-hospitalised-after-disc-brake-causes-wound-484217

> Van Anrooij's team, Telenet-Baloise Lions, put out a statement on Twitter saying: "Shirin Van Anrooij's forearm was injured by a piece of a disc brake in the crash following the start of the race. She will undergo surgery this evening. At this moment, it looks like no muscles or tendons are heavily damaged," 
>  Team manager, Sven Nys, said in an interview with Wielerflits he has never seen an injury like it, but Van Anrooij was conscious as she headed to hospital.
>
> "It is an open wound and there is also a fracture," he said.

<sub>precis</sub>

Comment: Welcome to SE - please take a moment to read the [tour] and learn how the site is constructed.  Your answer is a "link-only" and could become empty if the remote site changes.   To avert this, duplicate the main points in your answer, and leave the link as supporting information and not the main point of the answer.

Comment: Eg ''Disc brakes have caused some controversy in road cycling with various occasions including a crash where Owain Doull (Ineos Grenadiers) had his shoe cut open by a disc brake back in 2017.''    https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/racing/owain-doulls-foot-and-shoes-cut-by-disc-brakes-in-abu-dhabi-tour-crash-314710